# Add and remove data when panning bar chart in D3

Tags: d3.js, data-structures

I have a large dataset in an array which translates into about a million 6-pixel wide bars,

Given that about 130 bars fit into 800 pixels of screen, I need to only display a portion of the data at a time.  Then, when the user pans the chart, new data will be added and non-visible data will be removed.  The user could pan right or left so data need to be able to enter and exit from both sides of the chart.

I feel like the solution involves D3's `enter` and `exit`, but I'm unsure how to implement it.

One idea I've had is to use `Array.prototype.concat` and redraw on pan.  Another idea would be to use `Array.prototype.slice`.  I hope those are fast enough.

Any examples?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are no examples that I'm aware of. Roughly, you would need to do the following.

- Draw the initial bar chart. Pass in only the data you'll display (i.e. the first 130 data points if your screen is 800px wide).
- On pan, get the translation for the pan. The x translation corresponds to a certain number of bars. Take off this many data points from the beginning of your data array and add that many to the end.
- Pass that new data array to D3 and redraw. [This tutorial](http://mbostock.github.io/d3/tutorial/bar-2.html) should give you some pointers. Remember to pass a key function to `.data()` so it knows how to match data to DOM elements.
- Similar thing on subsequent pans. Figure out how many bars have been panned and modify the data array accordingly (e.g. using `slice` and `concat` -- doesn't matter that much). Redraw the bars.

The concept is very similar to what's done in the tutorial I've linked to, except that the redraw isn't triggered by a timer, but by the pan event.

Comment: Passing the key function to `.data()` was the missing step for me. Of course the official docs are good, but [this link](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/constancy/#key-functions) was most helpful.

Answer (score 0):

There are fundamentally two ways to do this. One is that you draw all 1M bars using svg and rely on svg's built in panning. The other is that you draw 130 bars and redraw each time the user pans. enter() and exit() are useful for doing things to data elements in your set that are entering or exiting the scene since the last time it rendered. (d3 determines which elements are
"new" by calling a predicate function on each element. The function has a default but can be user supplied.) You don't actually have to use them here unless you want to be fancy. You can just selectAll the rects from last draw, and .data() them with your new data, and supply the usual calls for drawing rects.

Comment: Drawing a million rectangles is not a good idea, even if most of them aren't visible.

Comment: I've currently got the "draw all 1M bars" implemented and it chokes the UI.  In fact, it's why I wrote this question.  Another detail is that I'm using the [stack layout](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Stack-Layout) which can make the million bars more like 12 million bars.

Comment: yeah, this is a situation where I'd have tried to let svg handle it first and then switched to doing it myself if it didn't perform