# How to check with d3.js if element is in viewpoint (in visible area)

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js, dom

I'm drawing large number of elements and in many situations majority of elements are outside of view point.

I'd like to avoid processing expensive rotation transformations on hidden elements.

Here's an example:

https://blockchaingraph.org/#ipfs-QmfXtMeUdjWBPQHUNKvF3nkYR57aZz7qarW5qikEUYWJvw

Many elements in this graph are hidden (try to zoom out to see). But currently I have to render each element on every tick and it's getting painfully slow.

Here's my code:

```
function transformLinks(svgLinks, nodeRadius, arrowSize) {
    if (svgLinks) {
        var link = svgLinks.selectAll('.link').filter(needRedraw);
        //console.log("total:", svgLinks.selectAll('.link').size(), ',needRedraw:', link.size());
        transformLinksLines(link);
        transformLinksTexts(link.selectAll('.text'));
        transformLinksOutlines(link, nodeRadius, arrowSize);
        transformLinksOverlays(link.selectAll('.overlay'));
        link.each(function (n) {
            n.source.lx = n.source.x;
            n.source.ly = n.source.y;
            n.target.lx = n.target.x;
            n.target.ly = n.target.y;
        });
    }
}

function needRedraw(link) {
    if (!link.source) {
        link = link.parentNode;
    }
    return nodeMoved(link.source) || nodeMoved(link.target);
}

var minDistToRedraw = 0.8;
function nodeMoved(n) {
    return utils.isNumber(n.x) && utils.isNumber(n.y)
            && !(utils.isNumber(n.lx) && Math.abs(n.x - n.lx) <= minDistToRedraw && Math.abs(n.y - n.ly) <= minDistToRedraw);
}
```

I'd like to extend needRedraw() function to check for visibility. For now the function just checks if either linked node moved significantly enough.

Comment: Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20667450/add-and-remove-data-when-panning-bar-chart-in-d3) can help get you started. You need to `enter` and `exit` data from d3 selection based on some criteria (which can be wether their coordinates are inside the current svg box or not)

Comment: do not update on every tick of the force sim, keep a counter, `if (++counter % 10 != 0) return; counter=0;`

Comment: you can simplify the node creation, one `circle` with different fill and stroke color and width and only 1 tool tip text, set a class to control this by CSS for the different cases, what is the need for a `*` CSS selector to apply to the svg elements (in your own CSS and in bootstrap CSS)?

Comment: thank you @rioV8 for the suggestions

Answer (score 2):

Since I didn't find any out of box solution I had to get into those coordinate conversion stuff.

First, I created function that translates external container coordinates into SVG internal clients coordianate system - containerToSVG()

Then applied it on .getBoundingClientRect(); to get visible area in SVG coordinate space.

Then in the filter checking if both nodes outsize of visible area - do not redraw link.

There are possible situations when both nodes are outsize the area, but link can still cross the area. But it's not a big concern as long as user don't see link detachments.

Here's the code:

```
function transformLinks(svgLinks, nodeRadius, arrowSize) {
    if (svgLinks) {
        var containerRect = container.node().getBoundingClientRect();
        var p = containerToSVG(-nodeRadius, -nodeRadius);
        var r = containerToSVG(containerRect.width + nodeRadius, containerRect.height + nodeRadius);
        svgVisibleRect = {left: p.x, top: p.y, right: r.x, bottom: r.y};
        minDistToRedraw = (svgVisibleRect.right - svgVisibleRect.left) / (containerRect.width + nodeRadius * 2);
        var link = svgLinks.selectAll('.link').filter(needRedraw);
        transformLinksLines(link);
        transformLinksTexts(link.selectAll('.text'));
        transformLinksOutlines(link, nodeRadius, arrowSize);
        transformLinksOverlays(link.selectAll('.overlay'));
        link.each(function (n) {
            updateLastCoord(n.source);
            updateLastCoord(n.target);
        });
    }
}

function needRedraw(link) {
    if (!nodeMoved(link.source) && !nodeMoved(link.target)) {
        return false;
    }
    return isVisible(link.source) || isVisible(link.target);
}

function nodeMoved(n) {
    return utils.isNumber(n.x) && utils.isNumber(n.y) &&
            !(utils.isNumber(n.lx) && Math.abs(n.x - n.lx) <= minDistToRedraw && Math.abs(n.y - n.ly) <= minDistToRedraw);
}

function isVisible(n) {
    var result = n.x > svgVisibleRect.left && n.x < svgVisibleRect.right &&
            n.y > svgVisibleRect.top && n.y < svgVisibleRect.bottom;
    return result;
}

function updateLastCoord(n) {
    n.lx = n.x;
    n.ly = n.y;
}

function containerToSVG(containerX, containerY) {
    var svgPount = svgNode.createSVGPoint();
    svgPount.x = containerX;
    svgPount.y = containerY;
    return svgPount.matrixTransform(document.getElementById("links-svg").getScreenCTM().inverse());
}

function transformLinksLines(link) {
    link.attr('transform', function (d) {
        var angle = rotation(d.source, d.target);
        return 'translate(' + d.source.x + ', ' + d.source.y + ') rotate(' + angle + ')';
    });

}
```